# How can i map all actions to C# class not ASP?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want map all urls like /Home/User or /Home/About or /Home/Register or ...  to c# page like this:

for example User.cs Page is like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string run(UrlParameter id){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

i want when user send request for /Home/User .. Call Run function of User Class and show return value to user. How can i do that in ASP MVC?

can i do this with change routes in RouteConfig? now current of my MVC routes is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and when i call some url program run an asp page in view folder as default of MVC Project in c#.net.

For more explains:

I have protocol between my client side and server side program that is **JSON**. i want return string JSON when client ask something and for do it i do not need to asp page for rendering html, i only need to call some function that return JSON to client.

How can i do that with MVC?

Comment: Unless I miss your question, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how MVC works.

Comment: really my client program works all in javascript and i wants from all of my server pages is JSON that give to my javascript.. now what should i do? i don`t need asp or cshtml pages, i only need some function that return json for every actions in every pages.

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh i would consider integrating with asp.net web api.

Comment: Agreed, this is what web api is for

Comment: @Daniel A. White & @Dave A, thanks a lot for helping, I`m try to search about it, do you have some idea about how can i do it with asp.net web api?

Comment: @Daniel A. White, Oh yes, i found it http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api .. thanks so much guys.

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh you should have VisualStudio2010 or higher and install MVC4 with [Web platform installer.](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and then you should follow the WebAPI tutorial I've linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your question has two parts.

For the first part : Mapping a url to a page. This is *in a sense* what routing is. It maps a url to an **action**, which could be a page or maybe a resource like a picture, or a response like JSON data. Notice it's not always a page, generally a **url maps to a resource**.

Read the URL routing docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "/Page1",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Page1", 
               id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In the above example : fakedomain.com/Page1 will run the `Page1` method on the `HomeController` class and if there isn't any code you've added in there it will search for a `Page1.aspx` or `Page1.cshtml` inside your views folder.

I would recommend at this point reading about REST. I suggest this article : [How I explained REST to my wife](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife)

---

For your second part : How do you return JSON data. Well you use WebApi. See the docs [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833994%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

WebApi allows you to write controllers that return data based on the request. So if your client sends an Ajax request with accept headers set to application/json, WebApi will return JSON.

Also it follows the typical system of asp.net-MVC's controllers, routes and actions.

So to return JSON data that represents products you would have a ProductController that looks like this:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{

    Product[] products = new Product[] 
    { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", 
                      Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", 
                      Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", 
                      Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public Product GetProductById(int id)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

With asp.net-mvc4 and the default routing setup for WebApi the above controller would respond to the following URLs

```
This would get all products
/api/products/
This would get call the GetProductById and return ONE product:
/api/products/put_id_here
```

I would highly recommend getting all the pre-requisites like visual studio and asp.net-mvc from [Web Platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and then [follow this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

Comment: thanks a lot gideon and thanks Daniel A. White & Dave A for introduce me with WebApis